# Sci-kit Learn SGD Classifier Partial_Fit Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm using scikit-learn and the SGD classifier to train an SVM in mini-batches. Here's a little code snippet:

```
for row in reader:
        if row[0] in model.docvecs:
            TRAINING_X.append(model.docvecs[row[0]])
            TRAINING_Y.append(row[2])
        if count % 10000 == 0:
            np_x = np.asarray(TRAINING_X)
            np_y = np.asarray(TRAINING_Y)
            clf.partial_fit(np_x,np_y, np.unique(np.asarray))
            TRAINING_X = []
            TRAINING_Y = []
        count += 1
```

I'm using the partial_fit function to read in every 1000 data points and using np.unique() to generate class labels as per the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit).

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

> raise ValueError("The number of class labels must be " ValueError: The
>   number of class labels must be greater than one.

I'm a little confused. Am I generating class labels incorrectly?

Comment: i also got the similar error. Maybe can we fake the labels and rewrite them later ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `partial_fit` says, `Classes across all calls to partial_fit. Can be obtained by via np.unique(y_all), where y_all is the target vector of the entire dataset.`.

You seem to be passing `np.unique(np.asarray)` which does seem incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the error thrown by the program, I think there is only one unique class in your target variable. Please use `np.unique(np_y)` and get the number of unique classes that you are feeding into the model and ensure that it is more than one.

Also, your value to the `classes` argument seem to be incorrect, it should have been `np.unique(np_y)` instead of `np.unique(np.asarray)`